# Using atom as a git editor fails to wait for commit message, why?

Tags: git, atom-editor

I have configured my git editor both by:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

or

```
git config --global core.editor "atom -w"
```

based on some posts in StackOverflow.

And my .gitconfig file has oneline like:

```
editor = atom -w
```

or:

```
editor = atom --wait
```

However, when I tried to use git commit, the git aborted commit due to empty commit message. After that, Atom launched after that. If I typed in commit message, save and quit. The message in bash is:

```
 Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released. Function provided here: Object. Remote event names: destroyed, crashed
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Does it work if Atom is not already running when you commit?

Comment: seems not.. atom jumped out after I use git commit command.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's as if the --wait option didn't do anything. It seems that for now we'll have to rely on a different editor for commit messages.

Comment: What version of Atom and what OS are you using?

Comment: I got the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and Atom 1.26.1.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have atom installed, but I did a similar thing for VS Code.  Have you tried putting the command *and* the switch together inside quotes?

`editor = 'atom -w'`

I've been doing that with the Bash `EDITOR` shell variable, since my default editor changes depending which OS I'm on at the time, whether I'm using SSH or not; so setting it inside the Git config for a project is not a solution for me. But it may be for you.

So please try that and tell us what happens.

Comment: It does not work:

`/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: line 277: atom -w: command not found
Could not execute editor`

Comment: you might need to specify the full path to `atom`.  On a Unix you would put in whatever output you get from typing `which atom`.  On Windows it's probably in `C:\Program Files` somewhere, although I think the Windows installer may also put in a script in `C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\atom\bin\atom.cmd` (where "You" is your username).

Comment: thanks for the response, sadly, using quotes (`'`) to add `-w` or `--wait` at the end seems to not work, if I aboid the quotes it will find atom but it seems to ignore the switch

Comment: Edit: I'm using Git bash (Windows) and tried also: `editor = '/c/Users/<myUser>/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom --wait'`