# $ git commit --amend not altering/saving commit message

Tags: github, atom-editor, git-commit, git

I recently `$ git add .` some changes I made to one of my repositories followed by `$ git commit -m'INcorrect commit message'`.

I decided to change the incorrect commit message to *'Correct commit message'* using:

`$ git commit --amend`

The instructions I followed to do this can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages

I use Atom, so Atom opens with '**IN**correct commit message' displayed, which I change to 'Correct commit message' and save my changes.

After I saved the altered commit message, I did a `$ git log -1` expecting to see 'Correct commit message'; however, I still see '**IN**correct commit message.'

What exactly am I doing wrong?

**Note**

Just prior to this, I changed my git editor from Sublime to Atom following these instructions: [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

I basically used:

`$ git config --global core.editor "atom"`

and

`$ export GIT_EDITOR=atom`

I realize now that I didn't have to do both, but I also realize this probably didn't hurt either.

Comment: If you use something other than Atom as your editor (e.g., "vim" or "nano", etc), is the behavior the same?

Comment: @larsks will give it a go sometime later today.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37706443/1256452 but note that it may be broken in the current version of atom: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48886343/1256452

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were *two* things that fixed this for me.

**One**

As @torek pointed out in his comment attached to my original post, setting the *--wait* argument when invoking Atom blocks git from returning from the `$ git commit --amend` command. Apparently, this is necessary for git to successfully capture the altered commit message, rather than returning before the message has even been altered. Makes sense.

`$ git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`

**Two**

Apparently, if I did not ***explicitly save*** my altered commit message (command + s on mac), it would never get saved. This I had to do in order to get the commit message to recognize my altered commit message.

This might seem pretty obvious at first; however, if I altered my commit message and clicked the close window button ('x' at the top-left of the window on mac), something strange would happen...

If I altered my commit message, close Atom using the close window button ('x'), and then subsequently execute a `$ git log -1` command, the commit message would show the original unaltered commit message. *Nothing strange there.*

However, *if I then executed another* `$ git commit --amend` *command*, Atom would open and display *the altered commit message from the previous* `$ git commit --amend` *command!* This is very strange behavior if you ask me. Not being a git guru, lets just say this didn't clear up any confusion for me.

**Bottom line**

Append the *--wait* argument (`$ git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`), and ***explicitly*** save your altered commit message in Atom (command + s on mac) when performing a `$ git commit --amend`.